# HTML Input Tag onSubmit

Tags: html, extjs, input, onclick, return-value

I have a function which is fired in Input tag on "onClick". The function in turn generates a Ext.Msg.show prompt.

The function that is called in "onClick" doesnot return anything but the Ext.Msg.show (YES/NO) returns true or false based the button YES/NO. The event does not wait for the input from EXT, but just displays it and then moves on.

The question is, Is there a way to make the event wait for the input from Ext.Msg.Show rather just display and move on.

Thanks,
J

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always return `false`, then submit the form manually when the user clicks Yes.